# How to make a java backend Firebase database connection

Tags: java, maven, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I would like to use java to insert entries into my Firebase Database (java NOT in the android environment). Is this even possible?

If it is can you please help me figure out why I'm getting this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions$Builder.setCredential(Lcom/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseCredential;)Lcom/google/firebase/FirebaseOptions$Builder;

The problem occurs at the `setCredential line below in my maven project in eclipse?

```
    try {
        FileInputStream serviceAccount = new FileInputStream(file);
        FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                .setCredential(FirebaseCredentials.fromCertificate(serviceAccount))
                .setDatabaseUrl(url)
                .build();
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("ERROR: invalid service account credentials. See README.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Shared Database reference
    DatabaseReference database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
```

Answer (score 1):

From the error message it looks like you're including the wrong SDK, likely the one for the Android platform. Make sure you follow the instructions in the [Firebase documentation on including the Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#add_the_sdk). From there:

> The Firebase Admin Java SDK is published to the Maven central repository. To install the library, declare it as a dependency in your `build.gradle` file:
>
> ```
> dependencies {
>   compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:5.2.0'
> }
> ```
>
> If you use Maven to build your application, you can add the following dependency to your `pom.xml`:
>
> ```
> <dependency>
>   <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
>   <artifactId>firebase-admin</artifactId>
>   <version>5.2.0</version>
> </dependency>
> ```

Comment: here is my current pom.xml: 
  <dependencies>
   <dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.12</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
   <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
   <artifactId>firebase-admin</artifactId>
   <version>5.2.0</version>
 </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>

Comment: I am using a maven project in eclipse to try to build a backend code that will run on a server to upload data to my Firebase database for my apps to read from. I'm not sure where I have to put the "compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:5.2.0'" in maven.